# side by side images with captions using html5 only (without css or tables)

Tags: html

I want to place a few pictures side by side with their captions below.  However, there are a few restrictions.  I can use HTML5 only (no deprecated tags) and no CSS.

I came up with a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/michaelJordan2.jpg" 
            alt="Michael Jordan" title="Michael Jordan" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/jamesWorthy3.jpg" alt="James Worthy" 
            title="James Worthy" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/deanSmith3.jpg" 
            alt="Dean Smith" title="Dean Smith" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/royWilliams3.jpg" alt="Roy Williams" 
            title="Roy Williams" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Jordan</td>
        <td>James Worthy</td>
        <td>Dean Smith</td>
        <td>Roy Williams</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but my teacher does not want me to use a table.

I tried using two  blocks but that placed the pictures vertically.  I also tried putting all the images within the same  block with the same results.

I found that I could have consecutive  tags which would place the images side by side, but I didn't know how to add captions to that.

Is it possible to do this with HTML5 only (no CSS) and no tables?  Or should I just go with the pictures and leave out the captions?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

**Update**

I ended up putting the pictures side by side and then below that I put

```
<p>From left to right: name1, name2, name3, name4</p>
```

I'll have to save the single captions for CSS.  Thanks for all your input!

Comment: HTML isn't HTML without the style attribute. It's a part of the spec. What exactly are we after here?

Comment: You shouldn't use tables for layout. Tables are for tabular data.

Comment: *`but apparently I'm not allowed to use a table either.`* ...how so? Apparent to what?

Comment: you can almost achieve it wrapping img's in figure, and captions in figcaption, but good luck with spacing them evenly.

Comment: I'm taking a Web Design class but we haven't covered CSS yet so we are not allowed to use it.  I want to put pictures (along with captions) side by side on my web page but can't figure out how to do it without a table.  She says I can't put it in a table either.  I figured out how to put the pictures side by side but not how to put the captions in.

Comment: sorry, apparently was a bad choice of words

Comment: @albert, I think you have an answer there. The intent of the exercise is probably to introduce the new(ish) semantic elements.

Comment: @isherwood how's that? `<figure>` is `block` by default. And by using `<span>` you'll have everything misaligned. So without using CSS and `<table>` I'm really waiting for an answer

Comment: how do you add spacing to the figcaption?  when i tried it, it ignored the whitespaces.  i tried sticking a table in there but the columns were only as wide as the names.  thanks in advance for your help - i'm a newbie!

Comment: *`Or should I just go with the pictures and leave out the captions?`* **Yes**. Go without captions. Since you're asking - I'm afraid you did not get the assignment right... If it was an assignment at all

Comment: the assignment wasn't to put pictures in a row with captions - just stick some pictures on a web page.  i wanted the pictures lined up with the names underneath for viewers who don't recognize the people in the pictures.

Comment: My mistake. I assumed <figure> would be inline.

Comment: make new images with the captions in the picture. problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

***Tl;DR*** : use images only.

---

> *I want to place a few pictures side by side with their captions below. **HTML only!***

Since you need them **side by side** (no CSS and no `<table>` element), by using the HTML5 `<figure>` is not possible since it's a **block**-level element and the items will show aligned vertically.

So `<figure>` is **out of the game**.

Let's find than a HTML element which is **inline-block** by default: `<button>`

```html
<button>
  <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/0bf" alt="Lorem ipsum" title="Lorem ipsum">
  <br> Lorem ipsum
</button>

<button>
  <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/f0b" alt="Dolor sit" title="Dolor sit">
  <br> Dolor sit
</button>

<button>
  <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/fb0" alt="Amet consectetur" title="Amet consectetur"> 
  <br> Amet consectetur
</button>
```

**Stupid solution.**

*OK, what about `<span>` than?* **Nope. You cannot**. `<span>` is `inline`.

```html
<span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/0bf" alt="Lorem ipsum" title="Lorem ipsum">
  <br> Lorem ipsum
</span>

<span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/f0b" alt="Dolor sit" title="Dolor sit">
  <br> Dolor sit
</span>

<span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/fb0" alt="Amet consectetur" title="Amet consectetur">
  <br> Amet consectetur
</span>
```

*OK, so I cannot use `<button>` cause it's silly, I cannot use any `inline` element, so what should I do?*

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/90x120/0bf" alt="Lorem ipsum" title="Lorem ipsum">
<img src="//placehold.it/90x120/f0b" alt="Dolor sit" title="Dolor sit">
<img src="//placehold.it/90x120/fb0" alt="Amet consectetur" title="Amet consectetur">
```

...which answers your:

> *Or should I just go with the pictures and leave out the captions?*

---

*OK, so clearly I have some tabular data.* **Yes, you do**, so use `<table>`:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/0bf" alt="Lorem ipsum" title="Lorem ipsum">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/f0b" alt="Dolor sit" title="Dolor sit">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="//placehold.it/90x120/fb0" alt="Amet consectetur" title="Amet consectetur">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Dolor sit</td>
    <td>Amet consectetur</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: -100 for thinking figure's only can have one img. -1000 for using table, which user said they can't use. you literally just gave back their question to them.

Comment: @albert no. The answer is: use images only :) - and a few more.

Comment: @albert if you place multiple image with captions inside a single `<figure>` element than you get the same problem as in your answer or as in the example above which uses `<span>` - So, again, `<figure>` is out of game - Since they **cannot** stack next to each other (if used as wrappers for a single image).

Comment: you keep saying they can't stack together...they do in my example. also, not what you took off 100 points on my answer for. consistency.

Comment: @albert dear, read again: `<figure>` Elements cannot (at least not without using CSS) stack *next to each other** since they *are* **block-level** elements. You *can* use multiple images inside a single `<figure>` element but than you're in trouble again. By using several `&nbsp;` is a bad advice. If on your OS and device looks OK there's no absolute guarantee that on mine will look the same https://i.imgur.com/bmOeWqb.png. And BTW a downvote is not -100 points ;) but a badly formatted answer with a bad suggestion will always get a -1 from me (And I'll always say I was the downvoter) :)

Comment: i'm loving that you are living up to the rep of 100k user. thanks for explaining how scoring works on here, now lets work on basic comprehensions skills. downvote anything and everything! just be consistent. if you're going to be anti-community partially, lean all in! passive-aggressive + nonsensical answers? how are you not a mod yet? i never said using '&nbsp;' was a good idea, it is a solution. '&nbsp;' is for children. '&#160;' for life  yo. badly formatted and a bad suggestion? do go on. please compare and contrast with your answers.

Answer (score -2):

This is achievable using <figure> to wrap the images/captions, however spacing the captions underneath the images is another challenge altogether. You can cheat using `&38;nbsp;`, but I'm not sure if you have that option.

`<figure>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b805558f5db9300807f0865d59d238e3/?default=&s=160" />
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b805558f5db9300807f0865d59d238e3/?default=&s=160" />
  <figcaption>caption 1, &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;8nbsp;&nbsp;caption 2</figcaption>
</figure>`

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/ojdtq4kL/3/)